# i want to update arduino data on python gui but it is not happening please some one find out the issue

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

I wrote this code to read arduino data using dht11 temperature & humidity sensor and wanted to display the data on tkinter gui i succesfully uploaded the data but it is not updating i don't know why please some guide me in this problem

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial

Serial_data = serial.Serial('COM39',9600)

data = Serial_data.read()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x350')
label = tk.Label(root,text="hello").grid(row=0)

label1 = tk.Label(root,text=data)
label1.grid(row=1,column=1)
label1.update()
root.mainloop()
```

i am new on python so please try to be as simple as you can i will be very thankful

Comment: it misses data.open() and data.readline() to read data from arduino

Comment: `serial.Serial(...)` will actually open the COM port and `Serial_data.read()` will read data from the COM port.  However it will only read one byte from the COM port.  He should read a certain bytes from the COM port based on how the arduino write data to its COM port.  Also in order to monitor the data, he should read data periodically using `.after()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only called `Serial_data.read()` once and you did not update the label, therefore nothing will be updated.  You should use `.after()` to read data periodically like below (just an example):

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial

Serial_data = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5) # better has timeout set, otherwise may block the program

def read_data():
    # assume the data format: humidity / temperature
    data.set(Serial_data.readline().decode('ascii').strip()) # assume data is terminated by '\n'
    print('"{}" read'.format(data.get()))
    root.after(500, read_data) # period depends on how frequent the arduino writes data to its serial port

root = tk.Tk()

data = tk.StringVar()

tk.Label(root, text='Humidity / Temperature:').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
tk.Label(root, textvariable=data, bd=2, relief='solid', width=20, fg='black', bg='white').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

read_data()
root.mainloop()
```

And the output:

[image]

**Note that I have created my own `serial` module to simulate the Python `pyserial` module and the data returned are generated randomly.**  So you should modify the code to suit your situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir it helped me to find out my mistake and gave me a learning