When using python to control an arduino, how do you structure your code to continually check and execute each item?
I am trying to interface with an arduino via python to use it as a hardware interface for sensors and hardware. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to structure the code so that it will continually loop through and read each sensor and check to see if a button was pressed to send a command...if that is even the best way to do it. I am new to python and really need to simplest solution (logically/understandable, not necessarily cleanest).
The below code works in allowing moving a stepper motor one way or the other via serial communication based on the left or right arrow on the keyboard or related buttons in tkinter. I am now trying to read an analog pin from the arduino over the serial connection which the below code does...once. I need it to continually output the reading while still allowing a very high refresh rate of 'checking' the other existing code to see if a button has been pressed in between sensor readings.
The desired outcome is a loop of: was button A pressed?, was button B pressed?, report Analog Pin....repeat. But at a rate that does not practically impeded on the ability to control the stepper motors relatively quickly or overwhelm the user with a stream of sensor updates. Ideally the code would be checking everything constantly all the time with no delay, but coming from programming Arduinos where things have to be in serial void() loops, I'm not sure this is even possible with python. I thought putting the whole code in a 'while True:' loop might work but it just reports the analog once at code start.
Thanks!
import serial
import time
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import ttk
from pynput import keyboard
import tk_tools

step = 0
#ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600)




while True:


def quit_button():
    global tkTop
    ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))
    tkTop.destroy()

def on_button():
        varLabel.set("LED ON ")
        ser.write(bytes('H', 'UTF-8'))

def off_button():
        varLabel.set("LED OFF")
        ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))

def l_button():
        varLabel.set("Rotate Left")
        ser.write(bytes('L', 'UTF-8'))
        global step
        step = step + 1
        progressbar.step(step)
        p.set_value(step)
        print("Step",step)
        #varLabel.set("LED OFF")
        ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))

def r_button():
        varLabel.set("Rotate Right")
        ser.write(bytes('R', 'UTF-8'))
        global step
        step =  step - 1
        progressbar.step(step)
        p.set_value(step)
        print("Step",step)
        #varLabel.set("LED OFF")
        ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.right:
       r_button()
    if key == keyboard.Key.left:
       l_button()



        
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press)
listener.start()



#change the COM port below
ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600)
print("Reset Arduino")
time.sleep(2)
ser.write(bytes('K', 'UTF-8'))


tkTop = tkinter.Tk()
tkTop.geometry('400x400') #500 x 500 window
tkTop.title("LED control") #name in title bar
# Create a parent frame
parent_frame = tkinter.Frame(tkTop)
parent_frame.pack()


#define button images
upimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('voltup.png').resize((60,60)))
downimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('voltdown.png').resize((60,60)))

#label to display the status
varLabel = tkinter.IntVar()
tkLabel = tkinter.Label(textvariable=varLabel, )
varLabel.set("LED STATUS")
tkLabel.pack()

#label for HV controls
HVlabel = tkinter.Label(text= "HV Control")
HVlabel.place(x=300, y=40),

#button1 - ON
button1 = tkinter.IntVar()
button1state = tkinter.Button(tkTop,
    text="ON",
    command=on_button,
    height = 4,
    width = 8,
    bg = 'green'

)
button1state.pack(side='top', ipadx=10, padx=10, pady=15)

#button2 - OFF
button2 = tkinter.IntVar()
button2state = tkinter.Button(tkTop,
    text="OFF",
        command=off_button,
    height = 4,
    width = 8,
)
button2state.pack(side='top', ipadx=10, padx=10, pady=15)

#button3 - Rotate Right
button3 = tkinter.IntVar()
button3state = tkinter.Button(tkTop,
    text="Rotate Right",
        command=r_button,
    height = 60,
    width = 60,
    image = upimage
)
button3state.place(x=300, y=60)



#button4 - Rotate Left
button4 = tkinter.IntVar()
button4state = tkinter.Button(tkTop,
    text="Rotate Left",
        command=l_button,
    height = 60,
    width = 60,
    image = downimage
)
button4state.place(x=300, y=180)

#Quit button
tkButtonQuit = tkinter.Button(
    tkTop,
    text="Quit",
    command=quit_button,
    height = 4,
    width = 8,
)

p = tk_tools.RotaryScale(tkTop, max_value = 60, unit = "step")
p.place(x=300, y =300)
#print("step",step)
tkTop.title("Progress Bar in Tk")
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(maximum=1500)
progressbar.place(x=400, y=60, width=160)

value = ser.readline()
print(value)
time.sleep(1)
    

tkButtonQuit.pack(side='top', ipadx=10, padx=10, pady=15)
tkinter.mainloop()

re

tkinter.mainloop() is while True: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091069/i-want-to-update-arduino-data-on-python-gui-but-it-is-not-happening-please-some

Thank you pointing me to this example..I'm curious about the after() function..Does using that allow the code to "breath" long enough to assess the state of other variables

@Сергей Кох. Thank you, this worked! Being totally new to python the help is appreciated. I don't really understand what I am doing, but I can kind of monkey-see monkey-do lol

@СергейКох , how can I prioritize the outbound data over the inbound sensor data? This mostly works but if I happen to send a command to ardunio while arduino is sending data to python it freezes us. I need to prioritze the outbound bits over the inbound.
